# Google maps zoom level overlay

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I need to attach marker for many cities on the map. My problem is that due high density of cities around Europe and UK markers and labels overlay each other and entire visualisation looks terrible.

[image]

First thing that I can do is to use a smaller markers. But what should I do with label? My idea was to show just subset of some cities every time user zooms in display more and more.

But how do I make sure labels never overlay each other?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can check [OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier) and [Marker Clusterer](https://github.com/googlemaps/js-marker-clusterer).